# Is there a way to animate content filtering that uses display:none?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, flexbox, portfolio

I've been designing a content filter for use on my portfolio based of off this guide:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp

It works great, but I've run into an issue that stems from me not entirely understanding the JS included in the example link. The "show" class is added and removed to filter content, but due to it being dependent on `display:none` and `display:flex`, it is not able to be animated and is currently visually harsh.

I've attempted to use height, width, opacity, and visibility, but as you would imagine, without `display:none` I am left with huge spaces on my site. Here is a rough fiddle displaying my portfolio and the way I have set up the dynamic content and filtering.

https://jsfiddle.net/qc35ghpd/

Below is the JS from the w3schools site.

```
<style>
.filterDiv {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease 0s;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease 0s;
  display:flex;
}
</style>
<script>
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}
</script>
```

The results I'm getting are expected, so I'm really looking for a way to modify the above code that allows some sort of animation between the toggling of `display:flex` and `display:none`.

Comment: There is a lot going on in your example! Regarding your problem, since display is not animatable, I suggest transitioning opacity and something like width or height;

Comment: Bruno, there is a lot going on, unfortunately. I felt that I needed to include the other JS and classes because I got poor results trying to transition with opacity and width/height due to the dead and live IDs being added and removed from the item class.